# how can i pass my webform value in webapi controller as a model class using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

this is my ajax code that pass two values in my api

```
 function submitData() {
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: 'http://localhost:53893/api/login/checkLogin',
                data: JSON.stringify([username, password]),
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function (err) {

                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
```

this is my model class which i want to pass in my api controller

```
 public  class Login
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

        public string username { get; set; }

        public string password { get; set; }

    }
```

this is my api controller method that accept this two parameter

```
[HttpPost]
        public string checkLogin(Login login)
        {
            getLogin log = new getLogin();
     Boolean check =       log.checkLogin(login);

              if(check == true)
            {
                return "login done";
            }
              else
            {
                return "failed to login";
            }
        }
```

now what i want is accept this model class in my api controller i tryed lot but its always been null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js code:

```
            data: JSON.stringify({'username': username,'password': password})
```

API code :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public string checkLogin([FromBody] Login login)
        {
            getLogin log = new getLogin();
     Boolean check =       log.checkLogin(login);

              if(check == true)
            {
                return "login done";
            }
              else
            {
                return "failed to login";
            }
        }
```

Comment: still getting null value in my controller

Comment: create class and stringify the object from js, I think you know how to do that

Comment: sorry i dont know can u please explain

Comment: Hey! mention not bro.

Answer (score 0):

Data passed through ajax should have the same structure of data what it must accept.

Try to build a similar object

```
JSON.stringify({'_id': id,  'username': username,   'password': password}),
```

Or

pass them separately as a two strings and assign them to the object afterwards in the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public string checkLogin(string username, string password)
{
  Login login = new Login();
  login.username = username;
  login.password = password;
  getLogin log = new getLogin();
  Boolean check = log.checkLogin(login);
  if(check == true)
  {
    return "login done";
  }
  else
  {
    return "failed to login";
  }
}
```

Then in ajax pass

```
data: "{'username': '" + username + "', 'password': '" + password + "'}"
```